# MD5 hashcode using spring for http request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i want to generate unique md5 for every http request that will hit REST API.
So far i have just used String requestParameters but actual httpRequest will have many other things.
How can i achieve this ?

```
public final class MD5Generator {

public static String getMd5HashCode(String requestParameters) {
    return DigestUtils.md5DigestAsHex(requestParameters.getBytes());
}
```

}

**My Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/dummy" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processOperation(HttpServletRequest request) {
    serviceLayer = new ServiceLayer(request);
    return "wait operation is executing";
}
```

**Service layer**

```
private String httpRequestToString() {
    String request = "";
    Enumeration<String> requestParameters = httpRequest.getParameterNames();
    while (requestParameters.hasMoreElements()) {
        request += String.valueOf(requestParameters.nextElement());
    }
    if (!request.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        return request;
    else {
        throw new HTTPException(200);
    }
}

private String getMD5hash() {
    return MD5Generator.getMd5HashCode(httpRequestToString());

}
```

Comment: Could you show your Rest-Controller Mappings or Class ?

Comment: i have updated my comment . please see.

Comment: Interested why you would do this? Is this to compare requests? You need to define your boundaries. How far do you need to go? Heck, you can serialise your requests using ObjectOutputStream and hash the resulting bytes. You can combine all attributes/headers/query string and hash that. Why exactly do you need?

Comment: i want to implement messaging using AMPQ. and for messaging i need to have unique identifier and this idea striked best in my mind.Every message will have unique md5 code.

Comment: my aim is make it clear ,which message belongs to which request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see any issues with generating an UUID for every request and use that instead?

For example, you could generate the UUID and attach it to the request object if you need it during the request life-cycle:

```
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    request.setAttribute("request-id", uuid);
```

Comment: i want that when user requests for same thing again then my system should send same hash every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine request time (`System.currentTimeMillis()`) and remote address from `HttpServletRequest`. However, if you're expecting high loads, multiple requests may arrive from a particular client in the same millisecond. To overcome this situation, you may add a global atomic counter to your String combination.

Once you generate an MD5 key, you can set it in [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) to reach afterwards.

Comment: i want that when user requests for same thing again then my system should send same hash every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but in future maybe. I search and not found automated way to achieve this

```
@GetMapping("/user/{{md5(us)}}")
```